# Instagram Api Photos White lines

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to fetch user photos from instagram api.
The url i am querying is:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token={access_token}
```

Note that i am only using access token and there's no need to register my app. I only want to get user photos. The thing is It returns original images and not the square ones. Why? All I want to do is to get all photos in the same size, but it returns original sizes.I tried standard_resolution and every solution I met but finally, There's more than I thought. Photos even have white lines which is disgusting to be shown on my website.

P.S. I want to get all photos ,all of them in the same sizes and without any white lines. Guys,i know instagram so often changes these kind of  things,but maybe you've found the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Instagram url in standard resolution is always square:

https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/20759276_1125417337622604_960083034999095296_n.jpg

If you want to get the original image from this then use (changing url pattern):

https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/20759276_1125417337622604_960083034999095296_n.jpg

Some image which is not having 640 resolution than the standard resolution introduces white line.

in that case to get the original square image we need to go lower than 640x640

This is the url pattern for 320x320:

https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/20759276_1125417337622604_960083034999095296_n.jpg